# Git cherry-pick range

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

How can I cherry-pick commit `C4` and `C5`?

[image: GitTree]

I’ve tried `git cherry-pick C4..C5` but I only get `C4`. 
I think I don’t really understand how this range thing works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR version: `C4^..C5`

Unless a command treats it specially (and `git cherry-pick` does not), a range expression means "take all commits identified/findable by the right-side name, minus all commits identified/findable by the left-side name".  In this case `C5` identifies commits 0 through 5 inclusive, and `C4` identifies 0 through 4 inclusive.  Subtracting the second set of commits from the first set leaves you with just `C5`.

Another way to look at it is that if the commits are related, you get a "half open interval", in the same way that the integers in `(3, 7]` are `4 5 6 7`.

As with the half-open integer interval, the usual easy trick is to start from one step back.  Since the (first) parent of `C4` is `C4^`, `C4^..C5` does the trick, just as `(2, 7]` would get you `3 4 5 6 7`.

(This fails if there's no parent, i.e., the left side is the root commit.  In that case you need some alternative strategy.  Some commands make this easier, some make it harder, but for now we can just ignore the problem. :-) )

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. I think I understand how it works now. C4 and C5 are both made on branch b1. Is there a way to cherry-pick all commits made to branch b1?

Comment: Usually you don't want *all* the commits reachable from a branch label that are not reachable from `HEAD` (if you do it tends to make more sense to merge, perhaps with `--no-ff` to force a true merge).  If you do want that, however, you can make use of the fact that in `A..B` there's no requirement that `A` be an ancestor of `B`.  For instance, if `b1` points to commit `C5` and you want all commits from there back to the root, minus any commits already on `HEAD`, then `HEAD..b1` does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case, you don't need to use a range.

Example from `man git-cherry-pick`:

```
 git cherry-pick master~4 master~2
           Apply the changes introduced by the fifth and third last commits pointed to by master and create 2 new commits with these changes.
```

So for you:

```
git cherry-pick C4 C5
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Works perfectly, but I think in the real world I’ll need to work with ranges (because there will be more than just two commits).

Comment: Actually, I've ever `cherry-picked` only when I messed up. Rather than `cherry-pick` on ranges, I'd prefer `rebase` if possible.

Comment: hmm.. I don’t know if my real world scenario can be done using rebase… I create a new question describing the “whole” problem I try to solve.